# Apache2: Virtualhost configuration don't working

Tags: linux, apache, laravel

I want to add a Laravel project as a Virtualhost

My .conf (what's in the sites.enabled and in sites.available, too)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName leltar.dev
        DocumentRoot /home/feralheart/Project/leltar/public
        <Directory /home/feralheart/Project/leltar/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/feralheart/Project/leltar/log/%Y-%m/error_%d_%m_%Y.log"
        CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/feralheart/Project/leltar/log/%Y-%m/access_%d_%m_%Y.log" c$
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to reach the leltar.dev I got "Server not found" error.
I restarted the apache service before tried it and disabled the "autocorrection" in my browser.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you add leltar.dev to your hosts file?

Comment: yes, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this and it works

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel54/public
        ServerName localhost.laravel54
        <Directory "/var/www/laravel54/public/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a symlink from my `~home~/Project/laravel54` to `var/www/laravel54`

And I also have in the `etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.laravel54
```

After adding this run: `sudo service apache2 restart`

You should also run

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 storage && sudo chmod -R 0777 bootstrap/cache
```

in your project folder

Answer (score 0):

The efficient and secure method to create a virtual host file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin you@youremail.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/laravel/public
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        ServerName your-domian.com
        ServerAlias www.your-domain.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/your-domain.com.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/your-domain.com.access.log combined
        <Directory /path/to/laravel/public>
                Options -Indexes
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This approach ensures that the errors are properly logged along with the access logs.
If you use centOS you may not have the **/var/log/apache2** directory in that case use
**/var/log/https/**